# local sections in general position

Tags: vector-bundles

The following seems obvious-and-easy-to-prove, and yet I cannot find an argument beyond the trivial case $n=1$. Maybe someone knows about it?

Consider a real vector bundle of any rank $n$ over a base which is, say, a compact manifold $M$ of any dimension. Does there exist an open cover of $M$ by the interiors of compact disks $D_i\subset M$, and over each disk a continuous section $s_i$, such that whenever $x\in D_0\cap D_1\cap\dots\cap D_p$ with $p\le n$, in the fibre over $x$, the $p$-simplex $(s_0(x),\dots,s_p(x))$ is nondegenerate? (I also want the radii of the disks to be arbitrarily small.)